# add html code on button in android to open html page on browser?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, paypal

I want to add the HTML code on the submit button in registration form in android application. I want when the submit button is pressed then the output layout of that code open in the web browser with in the application.

This code include some text,URL and subscribe button for my android application client to put membership by Paypal payment.

I am newer in this field so please tell me the solution.

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="DriverGroupConnect@gmail.com">
  <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="AU">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="DGC Taxi Membership">
  <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="AUD">
  <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-SubscriptionsBF:btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Monthly Payment Option">Monthly Payment Option</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select name="os0">
          <option value="DGC Taxi Membership">DGC Taxi Membership : $25.99 AUD - monthly</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="AUD">
  <input type="hidden" name="option_select0" value="DGC Taxi Membership">
  <input type="hidden" name="option_amount0" value="25.99">
  <input type="hidden" name="option_period0" value="M">
  <input type="hidden" name="option_frequency0" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="option_index" value="0">
  <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_AU/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal — The safer, easier way to pay online.">
  <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_AU/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, first use a WebView to load the webpage.
http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-webview-example/

If your webpage is local, save the html file in the Assets Folder.
http://www.androidsnippets.com/webview-load-from-assets

Sample launching a webview in onclick Button
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_webview_layout.htm

Check res/layout/activity_main.xml in the sample, specificly in the Button.

```
<Button
      android:id="@+id/button1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@+id/urlField"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:onClick="open" <!-- Java method to launch webview -->
      android:text="@string/browse" />
```

Comment: sir,the solution you have told me i have already use this solution.the web view page in my application is open but the link on that view give error...

Answer (score 0):

You can take a `WebView` to open a browser and put the html code there...pass all required data through bundle to webview and use it there..

**To pass the data :**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,webViewActivity.class);

        intent.putExtra("key", data);
            intent.putExtra("key", data);
             ...

        startActivity(intent);
```

**To get the data :**

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
data= bundle.getString("key");
```

Comment: mam want to know how can i take a Web View to open a browser and put the html code there...and how to pass pass all required data through bundle to web view and use it there..

Comment: I gave you a sample to pass the data... please google about how to use web view....it's not a tough task to do...